# CodeIgniter3 order_by() how to use NULLS LAST in active records

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

I am using Potgresql with Codeigniter and i have query that returns null values in columns i need to use for `order_by()`. As i saw in many examples i found on SO and google none of them works.
When i tried this query in pgAdmin it works and puting null values on last place

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM accounts a
LEFT JOIN subscriptions b ON a.id = b.provider_account_id AND b.subscriber_account_id = 10
JOIN users c ON c.email = a.name
WHERE a.user_role = 0
ORDER BY b.following DESC NULLS LAST, b.last_updated DESC NULLS LAST;
```

and this is query in model in Codeigniter which put null values on first place

```
$this->db->select('a.*, b.*, c.*');
$this->db->from('accounts a');
$this->db->join('subscriptions b', 'a.id = b.provider_account_id AND b.subscriber_account_id = '.$client_id, 'left');
$this->db->join('users c', 'c.email = a.name');
$this->db->where('a.user_role', 0);
$this->db->order_by('b.following', 'desc');
$this->db->order_by('b.last_updated', 'desc');
```

So how i can implement `NULLS LAST` in `order_by()` function

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Modified `order_by()` function in "system/database/DB_query_builder.php"

changed

```
$direction = in_array($direction, array('ASC', 'DESC'), TRUE) ? ' '.$direction : '';
```

to

```
$direction = in_array($direction, array('ASC', 'DESC', 'ASC NULLS FIRST', 'ASC NULLS LAST', 'DESC NULLS FIRST', 'DESC NULLS LAST'), TRUE) ? ' '.$direction : '';
```

now i can use it like

```
$this->db->order_by('column', 'desc nulls first');
$this->db->order_by('column', 'desc nulls last');
$this->db->order_by('column', 'asc nulls first');
$this->db->order_by('column', 'asc nulls last');
```